# Python - pysmb mover diretório ou acessar subpastas para mover os arquivos

Tags: python

Estou programando em python para acessar o ambiente linux, usando o protocolo samba, pysbm, realizei as conexões com o servidor e nele há um diretório em que entram e saem pastas a todo momento, então usando o pysmb, quando há pasta nesse diretório, estou tentando move-las para a pasta aonde esta meu main.py

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

def list_folder(connection, shared_device, path, pattern_file):
        listDir = connection.listPath(shared_device, path, search=65591, pattern= pattern_file, timeout=60)
        for f in listDir:
            if f.isDirectory:
                with open(f.filename, 'wb') as file_obj:
                 connection.retrieveFile(shared_device, path + f.filename, file_obj, timeout=60)
```

mas dessa forma não é possivel mover a pasta com as funções que tem no SBMConnectiton, há alguma forma de mover a pasta em um ambiente linux?

Achei essa pergunta semelhante, mas ela não possui resposta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832638/copy-all-files-in-directory-subdirectories-from-samba-with-python